# Using jquery to animate then hide element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using this to display .antwort and apply an animation to its opacity. This works fine. However, when clicking again .antwort is hidden immediately without any animation. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".frage li").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).find(".antwort").is(".open")) {
            $(this).find(".antwort").css({
                display: "block"
            });
            $(this).find(".antwort").animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 1500).addClass('open');
        } else {
            $(this).find(".antwort").animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 1500).removeClass('open');
            $(this).find(".antwort").css({
                display: "none"
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for the animation to be completed, before assigning the display none, otherwise the display none will take effect immediately and you won't be able to see the animation (the element is already hidden).
Use the callback function of the animate method, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".frage li").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).find(".antwort").is(".open")) {
            $(this).find(".antwort").css({
                display: "block"
            });
            $(this).find(".antwort").animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 1500).addClass('open');
        } else {
            $(this).find(".antwort").animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 1500, function() {
               // Animation complete.
               $(this).hide()
            }).removeClass('open');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Reference: [jQuery animate API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 2):

This effect may be achieved simply using `fadeToggle()`

```
$(".frage li").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".antwort").fadeToggle();
    return false;
});
```