# Javascript function continues before finishing while loop

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with this while loop, I want to iterate a short animation 3 times, then hide the div running the animation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var count = 3;
while (count > 0) {
    $('img.arrow').animate({
        width: '+=25', height: '+=25', left: '-=15', top: '-=10'
    });
    $('img.arrow').animate({
        width: '-=25', height: '-=25', left: '+=15', top: '+=10'
    });
    count = count - 1;
}
if (count == 0) {
    hideDiv();
}
});

function hideDiv() {
$('.arrow_container').hide("slow");
};
```

If I remove the **hideDiv();** call, the animation works as intended(3 iterations), but if I add it, the Div is hidden after about half of the first "animate" call

How come the if-statement checking the **count == 0** does not stop it from calling the hideDiv method? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can find the [solution for chaining animation and hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299383/using-jquery-to-animate-then-hide-element) in jQuery here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animate call only triggers the animation, it does not wait until the animation is actually done. Therefore your loop runs through in no time and then count is 0 and div is hidden.

You'll have to use callback functions to learn when animation is complete.

See documentation: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

The css animations are being triggered, but they take time. The JS is not waiting for the animation to finish, just firing the animate command, iterating, firing the command, iterating, and so on. The 'if' condition is true before the css animations are done.

One solution would be to use css to set the final attributes, not jQuery. Like: 0-99% is your animation, 100% is display: none.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies, I chose just to set animation times and delay the function

Could there be drawbacks to this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var count = 3;
while (count > 0) {
    $('img.arrow').animate({
        width: '+=25', height: '+=25', left: '-=15', top: '-=10'
    }, 300);
    $('img.arrow').animate({
        width: '-=25', height: '-=25', left: '+=15', top: '+=10'
    }, 300);
    
    count = count - 1;
    setTimeout(() => { hideDiv(); }, 1800);
}
});
```

Comment: Should be ok. It might happen that the animation would take a few milliseconds more than exactly 1800 but it would probably not be noticable that the div is hidden before the animation is finished completely. Especially as the movement is only 25 pixels.

Comment: I was thinking the same, it is a very brief animation where in this case I would rather have it close a few ms early than late, thank you for the reply